# Mongoose model.create creates document but contains none of the value passed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack, mlab

So I have a mean stack backend for my app which basically keeps track of gym routines. In it i'm trying to create routines based on a name, array of sets, userid, but when I run it executes fine but the documents on mlab don't store any of this information, just the date it was created.
(this is the req.body sample passed to my routine.create below \"chest\"[{\"setExercise\":\"s\",\"repAmount\":0,\"setTime\":1}]\"59dbfd763645bb001185b86b)

```
exports.createRoutine = function(req, res, next){
    Routine.create({
        routine : req.body.routineName,
        sets : req.body.subroutines,
        userid: req.body.userid
    }, function(err, routine) {
        if (err){
            res.send(err);
        }
        Routine.find(function(err, routines) {
            if (err){
                res.send(err);
            }
            res.json(routines);
        });
    });
}
```

This is my schema for what I'm trying to create

```
var SubRoutineSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    setExercise: String,
    repAmount: {
        type: Number
    },
    setTime: {
        type: Number
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

var RoutineSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    routine: {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    sets: [SubRoutineSchema],
    userid: String
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Routine', RoutineSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model('SubRoutine', SubRoutineSchema);
```

and there is no documents in the routines table in mLab, but a subroutines table is created with the following info

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "59e2bc7d68ba4a0011f3897c"
    },
    "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2017-10-15T01:40:13.220Z"
    },
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2017-10-15T01:40:13.220Z"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

I'm new to this so any insight into why this is occurring would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second module.exports is overwriting the first. Either put them in different files or make the export different like perhaps:

```
  const Routine = mongoose.model("Routine", RoutineSchema);
  const Subroutine = mongoose.model(""Subroutine", SubroutineSchema); 
  module.exports = { Routine, Subroutine };
```